# guice, MapBinder and Parametrized Interfaces

Tags: java, guice

I am using guice and the MapBinder. I have the following Service interface:

```
public interface IService<K, V>
```

and two implementations:

```
public class AService implements IService<String, String>
public class BService implements BService<String, String>
```

I want to use MapBinder like this:

```
MapBinder<String, IService<String, String>> mapBinder =
            MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), String.class, WHAT_TO_DO_HERE);
```

since I can't do

```
IService<String, String>.class
```

in the WHAT_TO_DO_HERE part, my first thought was creating a marker interface for IService and then proceed. My questions are:

1. What is the best practice in order to do this in guice?
2. Is the idea of a marker interface problematic here? If so, why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a `TypeLiteral` [(Javadoc)](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html):

```
WHAT_TO_DO_HERE = new TypeLiteral<IService<String, String>>(){};
```

and the Javadoc for [`MapBinder`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/MapBinder.html) say, there is an appropriate `newMapBinder` method although you must wrap the `String` class also into a `TypeLiteral`.